# How to prove $e^{it\hat X}=e^{it\hat Y}+\int_0^te^{i(t-\tau)\hat X}i(\hat X-\hat Y)e^{i\tau\hat Y}d\tau$ where $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ are operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

When deriving the generalized Langevin equation with Mori-Zwanzig formalism, I was taught that one identity should be used,  that is, 
$$e^{it\hat X}=e^{it\hat Y}+\int_0^te^{i(t-\tau)\hat X}i(\hat X-\hat Y)e^{i\tau\hat Y}d\tau$$ where $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ are super-operator acts on operator of the Hillbert space of wave functions(e.g. the Liouville operator in Heisenberg picture). 
    What I want to know is, how to prove this identity, is there a name for this identity? I hope someone can help me or give me some references on it.

Comment: This operator identity depends on a continuous parameter, $t$. If you want to prove that $f(t) = g(t)$, one way to do it is to prove that $f(0) = g(0)$ and that $f'(t) = g'(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362466/on-the-application-of-duhamels-formula).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is my first time to hear about Duhamel's formula,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the 37 ways to re-express Duhamel's formula.
Define 
$$Z(t)\equiv e^{-it X} e^{it Y},
$$
so that 
$$\partial_t Z(t)= 
-i e^{-it X}( X-Y )e^{it Y}.
$$ 
Now, since $Z(t)- 1\!\! 1= \int_0^t d\tau~~ \partial_\tau Z(\tau)  $, you have 
$$ Z(t)-1\!\! 1 = -i\int_0^t d\tau ~~e^{-i\tau  X}(X-Y) e^{i\tau  Y}, $$
hence 
$$
  e^{it  Y}-  e^{it X } +i\int_0^t d\tau ~~e^{-i(\tau -t)  X}(X-Y) e^{i\tau  Y}=0,
$$

Comment: Reference needed for the other 36 :-)

Comment: Only for 31.5 available....

Comment: Agree. Though the most general version is proved via the "interaction picture"